# TinyMCE 4 - merge two elements to act as one

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

In code I use the media_url_resolver to paste a proper youtube embed with a surrounding div to keep aspect ratio. It looks like this:

```
<div class="iframe youtube">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtube_parser(data.url)+ '"></iframe>
</div>
```

Aspect ratio works fine as does the rest of the editor. The only problem I have is that when I click the div and delete it, it only deletes the iframe but leaves the div. This obviously is unwanted as I want te remove it in whole. I need a way to make them act as one.

I've been searching my ass of on the interwebs but can't find a solution for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `contenteditable="false"` on the outer `div`?  This will make TinyMCE treat the entire tag bundle as one element which can be deleted but you will not be able to modify just one part of it.